# Why this is not StringIndexOutOfBounds?

Tags: java

```
public String delDel(String str) {
  if (str.length() < 4)
  return str;
  if (str.substring(1,4).equals("del"))
  return str.substring(0, 1) + str.substring(4, str.length());
  else
  return str;
}
```

If I run delDel("adel"), it returns a, however, the length of adel is 4, which means the last character string index is 3, why isn't str.substring(4, str.length() out of bounds?

Comment: Same reason `"".substring(0, 0)` isn't out of bounds.

Comment: so the index number could be same as the string length, but just display nothing?

Comment: It is explained by the javadoc for the `String::substring` method.   Google for "javadoc String".

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))

Comment: You can go into the source code for the String class, find the substring method and trace the flow of the program. Starting there, it will branch from substring->String constructor->Arrays.copyOfRange. That should help. I'll leave it to some of the better responders to format that nicely in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is the implementation of the substring method of String class in java:

```
    public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > value.length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

As can be seen, the beginIndex is only checked not be be less than zero, and the endIndex is only checked against the "value.length" of the string to be large than it. Then, if this condition passes, then the requested substring would be created by below Code:

```
public String(char value[], int offset, int count) {
    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset);
    }
    if (count <= 0) {
        if (count < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(count);
        }
        if (offset <= value.length) {
            this.value = "".value;
            return;
        }
    }
    // Note: offset or count might be near -1>>>1.
    if (offset > value.length - count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset + count);
    }
    this.value = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);
}
```

In your case, because the count would become zero(4-4), then 'this.value = "".value;'